# Gsm sim card with shortcode number instead of ordinary long number

Tags: gsm, telephony, sim-card

I want to make an interactive sms campaign and i would like to use a shortcode instead of an ordinary gsm number.I have tried reading this document on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_code shortcodes but i seem not to follow how shortcodes are assigned.

Is it possible to assign a sim card a shortcode number instead of an ordinary long number and still send and receive sms like an ordinary long number would?.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about phone numbers.

Comment: and in any case, the answer is that you'll have to talk to the operator of the network to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fairly off topic but here is your answer :)

No it is not possible to assign a SIM card with a short code number. You must make us of a SMS service where they offer you a dedicated short code or a shared short code. There are also various charging schemes which makes things that little bit more complicated.